# UIPopoverController buttons beneath a table view

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I was looking to implement something like the image below, and really have no idea how it's done and was wondering if someone had a quick design idea (no code is necessary or anything). Is it a footer view for the table view? is it some unknown footer view for a popover controller? Is it some way to integrate a toolbar from the UINavigationController 'into' the popover? I guess I could always create a custom view and display it 'like' a popover. Thanks for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIPopoverController will actually do a lot of that for you. If you set its content view controller to a UINavigationController, the contents of that navigation controller’s current view controller’s navigation item will display embedded in the top of the popover. I believe setting the view controller’s (not the navigation controller’s) `toolbarItems` will have the same effect at the bottom.

In this case, it looks like they wrote a custom popover controller; it doesn’t have an arrow attached, and the top of it is shaded a little differently from the standard UIPopoverController. But I’m pretty sure you can use the methods I just described to achieve a similar effect without having to roll your own popover.

Comment: Yea, I found an old question after I posted this that I actually edited and commented on (lol) that had the answer posted later by the OP and it is to this effect. Thanks.